# Swapping cell values based on index

Tags: python, pandas

Given the dataframe `df`:

```
   Team     Points For  Points Against

0  United      36      51
1  City        56      30
2  Liverpool   28      45
3  Chelsea     24      24
...
```

I need to swap cell values on one column ('Points Against') for every pair or rows (0, 1), (2, 3)... such that:

'Points Against' `loc` at index `1` swaps with 'Points Against' `loc` at index `0`,

'Points Against' `loc` at index `3` swaps with 'Points Against' `loc` at index `2` and so on,

ending up with:

```
   Team     Points For  Points Against

0  United      36      30
1  City        56      51
2  Liverpool   28      24
3  Chelsea     24      45
...
```

How do I do this with pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible way:

```
df['Points Against'] = df[['Points Against']].groupby(
        (df.index.to_series()/2).astype(int)
).transform(lambda x: x[::-1])
```

Another, could be shifting up and down (creating two new columns) and selecting one or the other depending on the oddness of the index.

You should do some tests regarding how memory and/or process intensive could be those alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

We can use floordivision on the index, then revert the column, while grouping by.

```
df["Points Against"] = (
    df.groupby(df.index // 2)["Points Against"]
    .apply(lambda x: x[::-1])
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)

        Team  Points For  Points Against
0     United          36              30
1       City          56              51
2  Liverpool          28              24
3    Chelsea          24              45
```